# Unable to identify search box using NUnit-Selenium(C#) framework

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Specflow with Selenium C# on NUnit test framework, and is struggling to identify the following search box and entering search text -

```
<td style="padding-top:3px">                            
     <input type="text" name="txtSearch" id="txtSearch" class="smallTextbox" nkeydown="CheckEnterKey(event)">
</td> 
<input type="text" name="txtSearch" id="txtSearch" class="smallTextbox" onkeydown="CheckEnterKey(event)">
</td>*
```

My code as below doesn't seem to work -

```
var topFrame = driver.FindElement(By.Id("menu"));
topFrame.Click();

var searchBox = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("smallTextbox"));
searchBox.SendKeys("xyz");
```

Any suggestions please!!

Comment: "My code doesn't work" is not helpful. What is the error that you get?

Comment: Besides your markup seems to be screwed and there are multiple elements with class `smallTextbox`

Comment: probably was a copy-paste error while trying to post :(

Answer (score 1):

AS it is clear from the html that id and classnames are same for the elements :
so you can modify below code as per your requirement (Whether you want to click first , second or third element )

ReadOnlyCollection allelements = driver.FindElement(By.Id("txtSearch"));

```
        foreach (IWebElement element in allelements)
        {
          //Add logic here whether you want click on first or second or nth element
            element.Click();


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Always better to use Id instead of ClassName, Because Id is unique but ClassName may be multiple.

```
var searchBox = driver.FindElement(By.Id("txtSearch"));
searchBox.Clear();
searchBox.SendKeys("xyz");
```

One more question, in your html I see two input text with the same Id. You should commenting one input.

Comment: Thanks Ali, tried that as well...seems like the code itself is a skewed and selenium is unable to identify it.

Comment: Not getting any error. When I am running my selenium test it's not able to identify either with the 'ClassName' or with 'Id'. Then I used this in my code to switch to main frame and started working --
driver.SwitchTo().Frame("menu");